# Struts Submit Image Type

Tags: struts2

How can this same need implemented in STRUTS2 with simple theme ????

```
<a href="#" onclick="abcd()" target="_self" class="buttonRedSmall"><span>Help1</span></a>
```

I have already tried both

```
<s:submit type="image" cssClass="buttonRedSmall" label="Help1" />
<s:submit type="image" src="../images/Button.gif" label="Help1" />
```

This seems not to work

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<s:submit type="image" value="Help1" src="../images/Button.gif"/>
```

Please refer to the tag reference doc for details

[Submit tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/submit.html)

Comment: Hi
>><s:submit type="image" value="Help1" src="../images/Button.gif"/>

Even This does not display the Name on the Image..but rather as a ToolTip

My possibilities is to use a Image button with variable names of different process...

How to achieve the same

using Strruts 2.2.3.... with TOMCAT702x

Answer (score 0):

Try This as it worked for me:

```
<s:submit type="image" src="images/Button.jpg" align="center"/>
```